# Variation on Fermat Little Theorem of the form $p^{\phi(m)} \equiv p$ (mod $m$).

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Does the following variation of *Fermat Little Theorem* hold? How do you prove it?

> Let $p$ be a prime number greater than $3$. Then there exist a natural
>   non-prime $m > 1$ such that $$p^{\phi(m)} \equiv p \quad
>  (\mathrm{mod}(m)),$$ where $\phi$ is Euler's function.

Comment: What's the motivation for that variation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated, this is quite easy: just take $m=p-1$. Then $\gcd(m,p)=1$ and $p^{\phi(m)}\equiv 1 \equiv p \bmod m$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: let $m=2p{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a strange question. For any *m*, the Euler totient Phi(*m*) is the order of the group (**Z**/m **Z**)* of invertible elements of the ring **Z**/m **Z**. For any *p* (not necessarily a prime) which is co-prime with *m*, *p* mod *m* is invertible (Bézout), hence, when raised to the power Phi(*m*), it becomes $1$.